# SQL mycursor.execute INSERT code fails using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am using python with a MySQL server.

When I execute the line

```
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO characters VALUES(1,"Bob","Sagen",7,4,4,"Will","Bob's Abs Capacity","Left Hook","Forhead""""")
```

It results in an SQL syntax error, despite being correct when I use it in the MySQL workbench. The data items are meant to be hard coded.

Comment: Check the value of your string in a Python interpreter.

Comment: Your `VALUES` clause does not have closing parentheses.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks, it compiled! I thought it had something to do with the triple quotes but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider parameterizing your query that divorces a prepared SQL statement from data and avoid any handling of messy quotes or concatenation:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO characters VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

data = [1,"Bob","Sagen",7,4,4,"Will","Bob's Abs Capacity","Left Hook","Forhead"]

mycursor.execute(sql, data)
```